# Why isn't my image centered in the div?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work? I'm trying to center the image.

**CSS**

```
.img-center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <section id="whats-on">
    <h1>News</h1>
    <div class="img-center">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/my-image.png"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: It's because `img-center` div is 100% of the width of the page. Try setting a `width` on it.

Answer (score 1):

the `img-center` container has width 100% ( by default ) so it is already centered but covers the width of all the viewport . this is because a `div` is a `block` element and as the DOCumentation says

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).
>   The `<div>` element is a block-level element.

so you can remove the `display:block`

**option A.** add `text-align:center` to `.img-container`

for this option you can remove all other styles

```css
.img-center  {
 text-align:Center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <section id="whats-on">
        <h1>News</h1>
       <div class="img-center">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
       </div>
    </section>
</div><!-- container -->
```

**option B.** give the styles to the `img` not to it's container

for this option you need to keep the `display:block` to the `img` because `img` is an `inline` element by default

```css
.img-center img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <section id="whats-on">
        <h1>News</h1>
       <div class="img-center">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
       </div>
    </section>
</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Worked a treat.. thanks for your help :)

Comment: @KOB glad i could help ! :D don't forget to rate my answer as accepted. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code centers the container of the image (which is already full width aka it doesnt do anything), not the image itself inside that container. Just do this:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/463oquze/)

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply add `text-align: center;` to .img-center

Answer (score -1):

This has to do with your `<div class="img-center">` not having a set width.
Add `width:100px;` just to see.

See this : https://jsfiddle.net/s3x82hv4/